# Webpack: How to import only required font-awesome icons?

Tags: webpack

I import only 10 font-awesome icons like

```
import FaClipboardList from 'react-icons/fa
```

but webpack is downloading all font-awesome icons. Is it possible to download only what I require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar problem with react-icon v3. Apparently they used `.mjs` files and webpack wasn't able to perform tree shaking on them. What helped is adding this extension to the webpack's `resolve` list. (only worked on webpack 4).

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.mjs', '.js'],
    ...
  },
```

Apparently they stopped using `.mjs` in newer releases, but they also have some problems, so I decided to stick with v3 for a time being.

Here is long thread regarding this issue.
https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons/issues/154